# TCP socket connection from Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, tcp

We need to connect to an external application which is a pure C/C++ socket 
the end programmer asked me to open socket via TCP and connect, so my question

> What is the best approach to call a TCP socket from my Java EE
>   application.

Java EE application overview : `Struts` + `EJB`

Are there any bottlenecks by opening a socket from my enterprise app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) to get your work done. And you can put that in an EJB.

Comment: Well ofcourse Java Scoket, But my question is where to open it from ? Is it really advisable from EJB ?

Comment: I would do it in a JMS setup, a JMS Producer, and a regular consumer using socket.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best approach to call a TCP socket from my Java EE application.

There is only one approach: `java.net.Socket`.